# Switching between splitted Vim windows as commands

Tags: vim, popupwindow, window-resize, keystroke, switching

I changed my .vimrc file to automatically open two windows once I fire 
$vim my_file.py
So in my .vimrc file I added following lines
vnew previewwindow

The problem is that I want to automatically modify each window and resize them in .vimrc and taking out the line numbers from previewwindow.

I know in vim I can switch between windows by +w but I do not know any Vim command that does so.

Is there any command such as :selectnext or :selectw previewwindow !? so the focus would switch to other window then I could apply every window specific commands.

Is there any command in vim that it accepts combined keystrokes as an argument so I can easily use that command with combined keystroke symbol to be implemented in .vimrc

In my case any command such as :sendkey( w) will work for me !?
In addition I am wondering how can I prevent a window to become smaller than a certain width and height (like minimum values for w and h)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend any window movement command with `:wincmd`. E.g. to move the cursor to the next window you would execute:

```
:wincmd w
```

See `:help window-move-cursor`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `:wincmd`, so to switch to the next window (`<C-W><C-W>`), you'd use `:wincmd w`. This is a special command for window commands; in general, you can use `:normal` to execute normal mode commands, so `:execute "normal! \<C-w>\<C-w>"` would be equivalent here.